# what should i use php mysql or json file to retrieve data?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am developing online exam system for MCQ based Exam in php and mysql.

**My database structure is as follows :**

> tests table -> Store data when admin create
>
> questions table -> store questions with 5 option and ans
>
> testtaken table -> store data of user give exam (inserting  1 row when
>   user give new test)
>
> ans table-> store ans given by user

Now at user end i am currently using direct MySQL query from database and display 200 questions using jquery ui tabs.

From Past few weeks i analysed many things for online exam from here and there.
I come to conclusion that for questions which will be around 200 or more i will create .JSON file from database once.When users give exam every time it will not go to database and take data from JSON file.

So Is my desicion is good or using direct mysql quires every time  ??
I am doing this for future because mysql will load slowly when many users give tests at a time.

Thanks in advance

> **EDIT :**
>   - I cant use php pagination with ajax Because we have timer in exam page so user may lose time at time of loading question using
>   pagination ( May be possible internet problem so high time waste for
>   users ).

Comment: Optimized tables and queries should have no problems with that kind of capacity still being able to query fast. If you index the right fields there would likely be very little performance strains. Databases are meant to be used my a very high traffic and millions of rows, so likely yours will not be taxed.

Comment: My question_body fileld used many space because it contains images(base64) and losts of text...so how to optimize ?

Comment: I don't store images in a database personally, but I have read that stored images will slow your database down a bit.

Comment: yes thats why i decided to create json file because once i created no need to reload it from db.. users come and test will be loaded from JSON file i just want to know there is any limitation or cons of JSON when high traffics ??

Comment: You should also use pagination, I don't imagine you will show all 200 questions on one page?? Pagination will make it faster as well, despite the embedded images.

Comment: at time i have to display only one question ..But you said pagination i just used it but  imagine if many users give test at a time than lots of  queries and server load i want to smooth experience to users.

Comment: Like I say, an optimized database with good queries shouldn't be an issue. I mean how many people are you talking about simultaneously?

Comment: 500 to 1000 in some tests

Comment: I personally don't think you will have an issue, but that is my opinion.

Comment: You can save all records in session when you start quiz and send next question from session no need to communicate with database every time to get question;

Answer (score 0):

Improve yoir db design u will feel better. For example, u can just store pass fail for users, or keep just wrong answers that can be in another table with user_id. Besides, even if you create a file its going to be unsafe. So again, just compare with sending data and retrieve true/false value.

Comment: but problem arise at time of loading test it takes time to load 200 question with images and lost of texts... i will manage ans tble and optimize it but for Questions i cant do ..

Answer (score 0):

When your data is not changing that often in the database, there would be no drawback of storing a `JSON` file and sending that to user every time. Definitely it is faster.

But from a design strategy it wouldn't be the best solution. What I suggest is to store the images in the file system and just store the `URL` in the database and query the database every time a user needs to start a exam. In this way you have more freedom with data you will provide to the user.

For example in the future if your question bank has 1000 questions and you want to select 200 of them randomly, this design would be more flexible